# Managing custom document locking to prevent conflict document

Tags: xpages, ssjs

I have a custom document process built into a ssjs object. When I click on the Edit button in a document in read mode, I call the method that sets a lock date/time and lock owner in the backend document and then returns true. Then the ChangeDocumentMode simple action can be used to change the document to edit mode. However, the first time I save the document (such as with a simple action), it creates a conflict document. It is likely that the frontend document is not aware of the backend document modification and save I did before going into edit mode.

If I change this process so that I let my document locking code set the two backend doc fields and then use context.redirectToPage, the document opens into edit mode and saving it from the ui does not create any conflict documents. However, if after using my code to unlock the document I use the Open Page simple action to go to "Previous Page" to exit the document, it goes only back to read mode instead of actually closing the document. I am sure that the initial redirectToPage disrupted the history and causes this problem.

The question: Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can lock the document before going into edit mode, go into edit mode, save without causing conflict documents, and still be able to exit using the Open Page simple action (after unlocking the document)?

Here is a sample of the relevant code for locking, including code to go into edit mode:

```
thisDoc.replaceItemValue("LockOwner",context.getUser().getCommonName());
thisDoc.replaceItemValue("LockDate",session.createDateTime(@Now()));
thisDoc.save();
var url = view.getPageName()+"?action=editDocument&documentId="+thisDoc.getNoteID();
context.redirectToPage(url);
```

Comment: use native locking technique (database property and `Document.lock()`)

Comment: Thanks, Frantisek, but that is the first thing we considered long ago, but the built-in doc locking has some problems that make it not the perfect fit in this case. If I remember correctly, the main issue was that you have one master lock server and not all of our users (on a wide distribution) can access that server (because of location issues). There might have been other reasons, but I am not remembering them right now.

Comment: locking in distributed environment may be troublesome, and making locks by saving flags into documents will make it only worse - in fact different users may lock their versions independently, what leads to save conflict. rethink your scenario - either setup global "lock" server, or divide documents to groups with their individual local lock servers. in any case, you need to make the lock visible to all instantly.

Comment: Domino's built-in functionality stores basically the same two flags (user name and date/time) on locked documents. It just takes care of the management process. Nevertheless, my way is still a bit troublesome, you are right. I will have to revisit the doc lock db idea to see if there was a reason why I chose not to go that route in the past.

Comment: I completely forgot two things: 1) First, I should have mentioned that these are web apps and, 2) built-in document locking functionality does not work on web apps. I will update my original post.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case. If your application is the way users access the documents, I would recommend not to write anything into the documents for locking - you only end up with the need for an unlock admin function for users who disconnected (network, close browser, crash) before unlocking. 
The way locking is done e.g in WebDAV is a in-server-memory time lock that a call renews every 30 seconds. You would use a classic Ajax call for that.

The openNTF WebDAV for Domino project has the server side of such a locking mechanism, you might want to copy it from there.

In case you must write into the document: change the sequence and update the document in the queryOpen event in readmode - that covers the cases where a user had bookmarked the edit URL too.

Let us know how it goes!

Comment: Hi Stephan and thanks. My doc lock object includes a mechanism for timing out the lock in case the user is either inactive for too long or exits abnormally. That said, I had not considered the queryOpenDocument (for XPages) event. That may end up being the simplest solution. I will take a look at the in-server-memory idea to see if I have previously considered that. It does sound similar to using applicationScope or the like, which would not work in replication. But I will check. Thanks!